# Angularjs - log in, stay on page, load div after authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am not sure how to approach this for my AngularJS site...

I need to load a login form to any page on the site (without leaving the page) then asynchronously pass user login info and get success or fail back and then load a div html template to the same page if login is successful...

Seeing a full example would be amazing but I do not expect that of course. However I can't find a single simple example of this on the web (Nothing that would help a newbie).

Can someone point at good solutions or at least understandable examples? .. or something similar that is not cluttered with unrelated code..

Comment: Check out this dudes method using interceptors. [Http-Auth-Interceptor](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth/tree/gh-pages).

Comment: Try this  http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app

Comment: Both of these seem close to what I need. I will study them. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a directive for my login, kind of like this. You can get a general idea of how it works.

```
.directive('login', function($http, $rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: " <form> " +
                  "<label>Username</label>" +
                  "<input type='text' ng-model='username'>" +
                  "<label>Password</label>" +
                  "<input type='password' ng-model='password'>" +
                  "<br>" +
                  "<input type='submit'>" +
                  "</form>",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            elem.bind('submit', function() {

                var user_data = {
                    "username": scope.username,
                    "password": scope.password,
                };

                $http.post("http://localhost:8001/api-token-auth/", user_data)
                    .success(function(response) {
                        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + response.token;
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('event:login-confirmed');
                        elem.slideUp();
                }); 

                scope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function () {
                    var main = document.getElementById("main");
                    main.hide();
                    elem.slideDown();
            });

            });

         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the code entirely but looks like a good beginning, thank you very much. I think I will have to use routeProvider to load my templates. I just wish samples around the web are posted WITH actual backend mock files,, like simple php to mimic back and and the whole integration process.

Comment: If you are familiar with Django, you can check out my git seed project that has a basic login with resource calls as well. [Angular/Django Seed](https://github.com/zackargyle/angularjs-django-rest-framework-seed)

Comment: I am familiar-ish with python/django. Thank you! I'll look at that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that does exactly what I asked about and can be adjusted to my needs fairly easily.
https://gist.github.com/clouddueling/6191173

It is created by Michael Calkins who I find to be one of the most clear and easy to understand sources for AngularJs tutoring. I found his videos on youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHMVP5aLAPM